# Find result based on id in mongo db using node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I want to find result from collection using node.js in mongodb. My code is as follows

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var assert = require('assert');
MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
    assert.equal(null, err);
    console.log("Mongo db Connected correctly to server.");
    db.close();
})

MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db){
   collection.findOne({_id:req.body.Id},function(err, docs) {
         console.log("Printing docs from Array. count " + JSON.stringify(docs)); 
   });
});
```

I am not able to get required result.Getting error collection is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

Try convert id to ObjectId:

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var ObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID;
var assert = require('assert');
MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
    assert.equal(null, err);
    console.log("Mongo db Connected correctly to server.");
    db.close();
})

MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db){
   db.collection('collectionName').findOne({_id:new ObjectID(req.body.Id)},function(err, docs) {
         console.log("Printing docs from Array. count " + JSON.stringify(docs)); 
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define which collection you're going to query:

```
db.collection('CollectionName').findOne({_id: req.body.Id}, function(err, docs) {
    console.log("Printing docs from Array. count " + JSON.stringify(docs)); 
    db.close();
});
```

[Node.js MongoDB Driver API - findOne](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Collection.html#findOne)